# Add some code so that when you press the F9 key the highscores file is loaded, and when you press the F10 key the file is saved

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

Adding some code so that when you press the F9 key the high scores file is loaded, and when you press
the F10 key the file is saved.
I have tried this code but I have gotten nothing from it so far, any ideas?

Comment: Where is "this code"?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60518834/edit) your question and add the code you tried. Then describe exactly what doesn't work as expected.